# Difference between two particular dates

Tags: java, date

I have two dates 20-03-2011 and 1-04-2011,stored as String.How can I parse this into date format and calculate the difference between the two dates?

Comment: First you need to parse them to `Date` (search for `SimpleDateFormat` on SO) and the simply subtract `date.getTime()`. Result is in milliseconds.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz   I tried the below code ,but shows error as unparseable date.DateFormat formatter ; 
           Date date1 ; 
           Date date2;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
            try {
           date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(LeaveStartDate);
           System.out.println("date1--------"+date1);
          } catch (ParseException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          }

Comment: @rak Your dates "20-03-2011" and "1-04-2011" don't have the format `dd/MMM/yy`.

Answer (score 4):

The following is one solution, as there are numerous ways we can achieve this:

```
 import java.util.*; 
 int syear = 2000;
 int eyear = 2000;
 int smonth = 2;//Feb
 int emonth = 3;//Mar
 int sday = 27;
 int eday = 1;
 Date startDate = new Date(syear-1900,smonth-1,sday);
 Date endDate = new Date(eyear-1900,emonth-1,eday);
 int difInDays = (int) ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing explained here: [Parse A Java Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339781/parse-a-java-date)

And calculating differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100373/66686

Comment: The way of calculating diff on that link is retarded - would never guess somebody would use while loop for DateDiff. So - it's much better using any of the answers available on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) :

```
public void diff(String str1, String str2)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-mm-yyyy");
        final DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(FMT.parseDateTime(str1));
        final DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(FMT.parseDateTime(str2));
        Days days = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use parse function in `java.text.DateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long getDateDiff(String str1, String str2) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(str1);
    Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(str2);

    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small program I whipped up to illustrate how you might want to do this. Beware, though, it may contain bugs, as I've only tested it with a handful of example dates.

You should *always* thoroughly unit test any code containing date calculations, as the Java API for doing all this stuff is very clunky, and always seems to produce buggy code. When possible, use a nicer Date and Time API, such as [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is what is used at my work place.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFun {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      String dateOne = "20-03-2011 06:44:03 GMT";
      String dateTwo = "25-03-2011 23:12:59 GMT";
      String format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
      System.out.println(getDiff(parseDateString(format, dateTwo), 
                  parseDateString(format, dateOne)));
      dateOne = "20-03-2011 GMT";
      dateTwo = "1-04-2011 GMT";
      format = "dd-MM-yyyy z";
      System.out.println(getDiff(parseDateString(format, dateOne), 
                  parseDateString(format, dateTwo)));
   }

   private static Calendar parseDateString(final String format, 
                  final String date) throws ParseException {
      final Date parsed = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date);
      final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(parsed);
      return cal;
   }

   private static TimeDiff getDiff(final Calendar calOne, final Calendar calTwo) {
      return new TimeDiff(Math.abs(calOne.getTimeInMillis() - calTwo.getTimeInMillis()));
   }

   private static class TimeDiff {
      private static final long MS_IN_SECOND = 1000;
      private static final long MS_IN_MINUTE = MS_IN_SECOND * 60;
      private static final long MS_IN_HOUR = MS_IN_MINUTE * 60;
      private static final long MS_IN_DAY = MS_IN_HOUR * 24;
      private final long days;
      private final long hours;
      private final long minutes;
      private final long seconds;
      private final long milliseconds;
      TimeDiff(final long msDiff) {
         long msRemainder = msDiff;
         days = msRemainder / MS_IN_DAY;
         msRemainder = msRemainder - (days * MS_IN_DAY);
         hours = msRemainder / MS_IN_HOUR;
         msRemainder = msRemainder - (hours * MS_IN_HOUR);
         minutes = msRemainder / MS_IN_MINUTE;
         msRemainder = msRemainder - (minutes * MS_IN_MINUTE);
         seconds = msRemainder / MS_IN_SECOND;
         msRemainder = msRemainder - (seconds * MS_IN_SECOND);
         milliseconds = msRemainder;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "TimeDiff[days: " + days + ", hours: " + 
                  hours + ", minutes: " + minutes + 
                  ", seconds: " + seconds + ", milliseconds: " + 
                  milliseconds + "]";
      }
   }
}
```

If anyone spots a bug in this, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
public void compareDate(String date1, String date2){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(format.parse(date1));
    calendar2.setTime(format.parse(date2));
    long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
    long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println("\nThe Date Different Example");
    System.out.println("Time in milliseconds: " + diff+ " milliseconds.");
    System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds+ " seconds.");
    System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
    System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
    System.out.println("Time in days: " + diffDays + " days.");
}
```